# Add custom button in jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

Can we add custom button in jtable. Is there any option available for creating a button?
Means  If I want a button for creating PDF, then how can I shall do?

Answer (score 6):

To insert a button you have to use the `display:` function , and customize it to your choice; ie i created a column with a button: the variable `data` contains the data for the current record.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable({
        title: 'The Student List',
        paging: true, //Enable paging
        pageSize: 10, //Set page size (default: 10)
        sorting: true, //Enable sorting
        defaultSorting: 'Name ASC', //Set default sorting
        actions: {
            listAction: '/Demo/StudentList',
            deleteAction: '/Demo/DeleteStudent',
            updateAction: '/Demo/UpdateStudent',
            createAction: '/Demo/CreateStudent'
        },
        fields: {
            StudentId: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Name',
                width: '40%'
            },
            EmailAddress: {
                title: 'Email address',
                list: false
            },
            Password: {
                title: 'User Password',
                type: 'password',
                list: false
            },
            Gender: {
                title: 'Gender',
                width: '20%',
                options: { 'M': 'Male', 'F': 'Female' }
            },
            MyButton: {
                title: 'MyButton',
                width: '40%',
                display: function(data) {
                     return '<button type="button" onclick="alert(' + data.record.StudentId + ')">create PDF</button> ';
                }
            },

        }
    });

    //Load student list from server
    $('#StudentTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

Comment: Yes this is good but I want to go one step further my question is that if we give this button a class like class='button1' than can we use this class to attach any event to this button

Comment: when i use the above code i get an error data not defined

Comment: About error, the result of the page (ie listAction: '/Demo/StudentList',) should be a json object. in php:
`$row = array("name"=>"me");
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $num_rows;
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
print json_encode($jTableResult);`
so data.record.name is defined.
Also take a look at the documentation for more help:
http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-display
About attach event, try this, it should work:
`$( ".myclassbutton" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
`